# StoredProcedureQuery not working after update to SpringBoot 3.0.6

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

In my project i was using first the SpringBoot version 2.7.3. There i was calling a stored procedure with help StoredProcedureQuery. So i'm first registering all needed parameters with help of the method registerStoredProcedureParameter(String var1, Class var2, ParameterMode var3) and the set the parameters with help of the method setParameter(String var1, Object var2).

However everything was working before the update of SpringBoot to 3.0.6.
After the update i needed to change all persistence imports from javax.* to jakarta.*. All other DB calls are working exactly as before. Only this StoredProcedureQuery call is returning the
following error:

```
Error parsing INTEGER literal value starting at index 23.  Error Detail:Invalid character ':' found in INTEGER literal.
Full SQL statement text= call SYSPROC.***(:NAN_IN,:EINHEIT_IN,:LAGER_IN,:PER_DATUM_VON_IN,:PER_DATUM_BIS_IN,:TRACE_SCHALTER_IN,:STATUS_OUT,:MESSAGE_OUT,:SQL_CODE_OUT,:SQL_SEQ_OUT)  ERRORCODE=-4463, SQLSTATE=42601
```

I'm using the following jdbc driver:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
      <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
      <version>4.32.28</version>
</dependency>
```

I already tried different versions of the jdbc driver, but nothing helped.
Since the stored procedure call is entity independent i have to use this StoredProcedureQuery.

Any idea how can i fix that?

Comment: Can confirm that I'm having this problem as well. Not sure about what to do about it. Will probably downgrade to 2.x. May try using different procedure api to start with.